# Disable BootReceiver class when unit Testing using robolectric android

Tags: android, robolectric

Disable BootReceiver class when unit Testing using robolectric android

Is this possible during unit test ?

Comment: Is broadcast receiver in your manifest?

Comment: yes, but its possible during unit testing to disable it?

Comment: yes, I'm searching for example. It is possible with own custom test runner

Comment: okay then how?? can you post the answer so that i can test and accept it?